# Swift Displaying Game Center Leaderboards

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, gamekit

Right now I am trying to make a leaderboard I created show up. The player is authenticated just fine, but when the game center window opens it is very strange. Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to display this image:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.showLeaderboard()
    }
    func showLeaderboard() {
        var leaderView = UIViewController()

       var leaderViewController = GKGameCenterViewController(rootViewController: leaderView)
         leaderViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
       leaderViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "High_Score_Board"
       self.showViewController(leaderViewController, sender: self)
        //self.presentViewController(leaderViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish(controller: GKGameCenterViewController){
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

All of this is in my GameViewController. Also, even if this works, how would I access this method in my SKScenes? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import GameKit:

```
import GameKit
```

Make sure to add the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` delegate within your class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
    ...
}
```

That delegate requires a method which is called when the player taps on the "Done" button.

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the function that includes the code needed to display the leaderboard:

```
func showLeaderboard() {        
    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    // Remember to replace "Best Score" with your Leaderboard ID (which you have created in iTunes Connect)
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "Best_Score"
    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)
     // self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can now call `showLeaderboard` by pressing a button:

```
@IBAction func buttonShowLeaderboard(sender: AnyObject) {
    showLeaderboard()
}
```

Comment: showViewController crashes iOS 7 devices. Do you know what the code should be for iOS 7?